# Numpy not fond on pycharm but works on spyder

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda

This python code

```
import numpy as np

from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean

a = np.array([5,3,4,-1,0]);
b = np.array([2,4,0,-5,-2]);

dist = euclidean(a,b);

print ("Distancia = "+ str(dist) );

simil = 1/(1+dist);

print ('Similitud = '+ str(simil) );
```

In spyder runs without a  problem but in pycharm I get this error message

```
/home/user/anaconda3/envs/prueba2/bin/python /home/user/PycharmProjects/prueba2/prueba2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/prueba2/prueba2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

and this is the project interpreter

[image]

Comment: Could be that you're using different versions of python in Spyder and Pycharm.

Comment: python 3.6.4 both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pip3 install numpy
pip install numpy
```

> use above command in terminal and install numpy for python 3.6 then
>   try again.

Comment: above screenshot is of pycharm of spyder?

Comment: its pycharm, numpy its not on the list but  I installed it